# Input react native - press in crashes application

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

When press input text to 3 seconds, show the message "Application name is stopped", how to correct this?...........................................................................................
[image]

my component

```
return (
        <ReactNative.TextInput
            ref={(ref: any) => { this.input = ref; }}
            style={styleInputFormDefault}
            numberOfLines={this.state.numberOfLines}
            blurOnSubmit={true}
            editable={this.state.editable}
            underlineColorAndroid={"transparent"}
            value={this.state.value}
            multiline={this.state.multiline}
            placeholder={this.state.placeholder}
            keyboardType="default"
            onChange={event => {
                this.value = event.nativeEvent.text;
            }}
            onEndEditing={event => {
                this.value = event.nativeEvent.text;
                if (this.props.onChange != undefined) {
                    !this.props.onChange(this.value);
                }
            }}
            returnKeyType={this.state.returnKeyType}
            onSubmitEditing={() => {
                if (this.props.onSubmit != undefined) {
                    this.props.onSubmit(this);
                }
            }}
            onFocus={() => {
                if (this.props.onFocus != undefined) {
                    this.props.onFocus();
                };
            }}
            onBlur={() => {
                if (this.props.onBlur != undefined) {
                    this.props.onBlur();
                };
            }}
        >
        </ReactNative.TextInput>

    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this fix - https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/17530

This fix is already available in a higher version of. react-native now - https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/24183/commits/6310ad1e9441d532f930eb89e38300dbd973a919

Answer (score -1):

Why are using the TextInput component like that? Simply import just the TextInput from react native.

Try this code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { TextInput } from 'react-native'

export default class InputClassName extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.input = null
    this.state {
      [...]
    }
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <View>
        <TextInput
             ref={ref => this.input = ref}
             style={styleInputFormDefault}
             numberOfLines={this.state.numberOfLines}
             blurOnSubmit={true}
             underlineColorAndroid={"transparent"}
             value={this.state.value}
             multiline={this.state.multiline}
             placeholder={this.state.placeholder}
             keyboardType="default"
             onChangeText={value => this.value = value}
             onEndEditing={event => {
                 // I do not know what you're trying to do here
                // Are you checking if the onChange props is a function? If so, do this instead:
                // if("function" === typeof this.props.onChange) { [...] } 
                 this.value = event.nativeEvent.text;
                 if (this.props.onChange != undefined) {
                     !this.props.onChange(this.value);
                 }
             }}
             returnKeyType={this.state.returnKeyType}
             onSubmitEditing={() => {
                 // same goes here
                 if (this.props.onSubmit != undefined) {
                     this.props.onSubmit(this);
                 }
             }}
             onFocus={() => {
                 // also here
                 if (this.props.onFocus != undefined) {
                     this.props.onFocus();
                 };
             }}
             onBlur={() => {
                 // and here.
                 if (this.props.onBlur != undefined) {
                     this.props.onBlur();
                 };
             }}
         >
         </TextInput>
       { /* Please note that you can also use propTypes in order to force (recommended)
          a specific prop to be the typeof whatever you want instead of using if/else */ }
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```